# ValueError: invalid literal for int() in my program and if statement inside a except

Tags: python, int, literals, valueerror, except

I have a program that takes input and adds it to a list and spits out the average of said list. I want to make it so you can type MENU and it will stop the programy() and let you either exit or restart the programy(). Everything works fine until you type MENU (all caps). Thank you everyone! :) Still new to python.

```
from functools import reduce

def programy():
    running = True

    print("I output the average of a list that you add files to.")
    listy = []

    while running == True:
        def listaverage(givenlist):
            print(sum(listy) / len(listy))

        currentnum = input("Please type a number to add to the list: ")

        try:
            val = int(currentnum)
        except ValueError:
            if str(currentnum) == "MENU":
                running = False
            else:
                print("Not a number!")
                continue

        listy.append(int(currentnum))
        listaverage(listy)

    answer = input("Please type either: EXIT or RESTART")

    if str(answer) == "RESTART":
        running = True
    if answer == "EXIT":
        exit

programy()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hullb\OneDrive\Desktop\average_via_input.py", line 34, in <module>
    programy()
  File "C:\Users\hullb\OneDrive\Desktop\average_via_input.py", line 24, in programy
    listy.append(int(currentnum))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'MENU
```

Comment: You are checking if currentnum is a string and then try to add it to a list as an integer. When you set running to False it will still execute listy.append(). In my mind you could just do break instead of running = False

Comment: you need to debug your program, there are multiple logical errors. for example: in try block, do everything that should otherwise work fine (hinting at the "list.append" and the following line) also, your menu related code should also be inside the loop.

Comment: adding to the comments here, the `try: int(currentnum) except ValueError: if str(currentnum) == "MENU":` is not correct as you're checking for a valid incoming integer value and not a string, and the if/else statement should be outside the try/except, and you don't really need the `else:` as that's the point of the `try: ... except: ....` to raise an exception if it's not an integer value input...hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes thank you!! I was kind of fuzzy on the try/except concept..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if str(currentnum) == "MENU":
    running = False
```

sets the `while` condition to `false` and stops the next iteration from running, but the current one hasn't ended yet, so in `int(currentnum)` you are trying to convert `"MENU"` to int.

Use `isdigit()` instead to check the value

```
if currentnum.isdigit():
    listy.append(int(currentnum))
    listaverage(listy)
else:
    if str(currentnum) == "MENU":
        running = False
    else:
        print("Not a number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is simple, you're taking a string as an input,
say if for exiting the loop i.e. MENU, and in line

```
listy.append(int(currentnum))
```

you're typecasting that to an integer. That's why you're getting the above error.
Without changing much of code, you only need to shift few lines to get that done.
Just move

```
    listy.append(int(currentnum))
    listaverage(listy)
```

under the try block, where if it is a number you do as required.
Also define the function listaverage(listy) outside the main program, unless you want it acting as a generator.

Comment: the error is before that actually, the if statement is not supposed to be within the `except` block of the try/except and the if/else logic seems a little incorrect as it's checking for a string input but then saying `else: print('Not a number')`

Comment: @FishingCode Right, error is above that but as handled, the above will make him get this work done, with just two lines of shift.

Comment: ok. where are you moving the lines you wrote in your answer..?